# Rigorous Bayesian Model Selection

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, measure-theory

I am learning Bayesian Model Selection. I want to understand the rigorous mathematics behind the idea of encompassing model. To be more specific, suppose we want to compare M models:

Model $\mathcal{M}_m$ : $\left\{ \begin{array}{l} y\sim f_m(y|\theta_m), \text{ where } \theta_m\in\Theta_m\\
\theta_m\sim\pi_m(\theta_m)\text{ ditribution over } (\Theta_m,\mathcal{B}_m)\end{array} \right.$

In standard framework (C.Robert(2007) - The Bayesian Choice), we consider an encompassing model by defining a parameter space $\Theta=\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^M \{m\}\times\Theta_m$.
I have 2 questions about this approach:

1. The new parameter space $\Theta$ is not a Cartesian product. How could we construct a $\sigma-$algebra for $\Theta$ from $\sigma-$algebras $\mathcal{B}_m$?
2. The rigorous derivation of the posterior probability
           $P(\mathcal{M}_k|y)=P(\mu=k|y)=\dfrac{p_kf_k(y)}{\sum\limits_{m=1}^Mp_mf_m(y)}$ where $f_k(y)$ and $p_k$ are the marginal likelihood and prior probability of model $\mathcal{M}_k$, respectively.

I much appreciate your answer or hints!

Comment: Regarding the first question: you are looking for a way to put a $\sigma$-algebra on a disjoint union of measurable spaces. This [can be done](https://mathoverflow.net/a/54924)